# vb.net import csv into Datatable double-quote issue

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

I have a large CSV file to import (and has to import on a regular basis).  The biggest problem is that one of the fields contains descriptions that use double-quotes.  So a field might have a value inside the raw csv file like this:

```
...,...,"100/5 OZ 5/8" x 1/2" x 1/2" Cube",...,...
```

I currently have simple ADO code that pulls the CSV into a table, but that won't work because of these double quotes :(  Currently I am just trying to pull the CSV into a datatable, but the final effort will be to push into a SQL Server table.

Simple ADO Code:

```
Dim cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Datasource='C:\csv\';Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited';"
Dim dt as new Datatable

Using tblAdp as new OleDBDataAdapter("Select * from [ZMES.csv]",cnStr
   tblAdp.fill(dt)
End Using

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

When it hits those " in the midst of the string, it truncates that row and moves to the next.  I need to do something similar to what I would do inserting quotes into a database in php (escaping the double quotes), but not real sure how.  As a test, I also tried LumenWorks CSV Reader and it faulted out on those lines.

Comment: Some of the quotes look arbitrary.  I get the ones after `5/8` and `1/2`  most of the others look arbitrary and as there are 5 of them, they seem mismatched for data enclosures.  Study your options for CSVReader via the CSVConfiguration class for quote and mapping options

Comment: They should look normal now.  I put a space in on accident.  I'm within a VMWare and RDP session, so couldn't copy direct from the code or the csv.  Typed it in and accidentally added a space. Now the 5 quotes look like they should.

Comment: Ths CSV needs to be properly escaped according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: If this portion of a csv line is the only portion that contains double quotes you could mask any double quote you find except for the first and the last one (per line) and then use your existing code to import the file. If one line contains more than one double quoted string (let's say five strings) and this problematic string (let's say the third one) is the only one that can contain double quotes itself, you could count how many double quotes you're not allowed to mask. Otherwise there's no way to detect which double quote to mask.

Comment: Like Jason Bayldon said, the csv file provider should properly mask double quotes (and commata for that matter).